# Refer to a list in Python from within the [ ] operator

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

While trying to optimize a one-liner that extracts values from a list of dicts (all strings that come after keyword/ til the next /) I got stuck in the following:

imagine this list of dicts:

```
my_list = [{'name':'val_1', 'url':'foo/bar/keyword/bla_1/etc'}.......{'name':'val_z', 'url':'foo/bar/keyword/bla_n/etc'}]
```

The numbers in val_ and bla_ are not related.

I am trying to extract all the bla_x (they could be anything, no pattern possible) words using list comprehension for 0 < x < n+1. I managed to get the index of those elements in the split string

```
[d['url'].split('/').index('keyword') + 1 for d in my_list]
```

But what I need is to access that value and not only its index, so I thought about something like this:

```
[d['url'].split('/')[the_resulting_split_list.index('keyword') + 1] for d in my_list]
```

As far as my knowledge go, that seems impossible to do. Is there an alternative way to reach my goal of getting an output of ['bla_1', 'bla_2', ....., 'bla_n'] without having to run the split('/') operation twice in the list comprehension?

Let's not care about exceptions for now and assume input data is always correct.

Comment: With a sufficiently recent Python version (3.8, I think) you could do something like `(tmp := d['url'].split('/'))[tmp.index('keyword') + 1]` - but your code would be vastly more readable if you didn't try to do the whole job in one line.

Comment: Yeah just forget the list comprehension and use a normal loop.

Comment: @jasonharper that looks interesting thanks!